How to use signal with Angular Reactive Forms
I have a template driven form in Angular 17 and I can use signal with my form like this:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <input [ngModel]='firstName()' (ngModelChange)="firstName.set($event)">
    <input [ngModel]='lastName()' (ngModelChange)="lastName.set($event)">
  `,
})
export class App {
  firstName= signal('first name');
  lastName= signal('last name');
} 

Any idea how can I use angular signals with reactive forms?

When working with template driven you can just do.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]='firstName'>
    <input [(ngModel)]='lastName'>
  `,
})
export class App {
  firstName= signal('first name');
  lastName= signal('last name');
} 

When working with reactive, there is more code setup, but here is a snippet, tutorial and forked stackblitz demoing how to implement.
You cannot implement the signal for each individual control but you can convert the control changes to a signal and use it along with combinations of computed and effect to achieve multiple scenarios.
Angular (17+) Reactive Forms + Signals & StandAlone Components
...
export class ProfileEditorComponent {
  profileForm!: FormGroup;
  firstnameSignal: Signal<any> | undefined;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
      firstname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      lastname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      email: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      gender: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      country: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });

    // firstNameSignal is created using the toSignal function.
    // represents the value of the 'firstName' form control.
    // so now instead of manually subscribing to the valueChanges of the form control, we can directly use the signal in our template
    this.firstnameSignal = toSignal(
      this.profileForm.get('firstname')?.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(300)) ??
        of(null),
      {}
    );
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('submited values: ', this.profileForm.value);
  }
}

Forked Stackblitz

Let's suppose my form has an initial value and that value is already is on a subject or another signal, how can I use that value of subject or signal for to initialised my form?

@AlirezaAhmadi On ngOnInit  subscribe to the observable and initialize the form. If you are using signal, then use effect to trigger the form initialization.

In template driven I don't want to subscribe my subject. simply I will convert the subject to signal and [ngModel] will bind the converted subject to my form element.

@AlirezaAhmadi Like the below comment mentioned, signals in reactive is a work in progress, these answer provide you the best at the current moment to achieve what you want

@AlirezaAhmadi Its a bad idea, to use a subject in ngModel, one way binding is fine, two way binding will not work! the subject will not get updated with [(ngModel)] or with the set method

Why doesn't this have any upvotes? Weird. I was just looking for the simplest thing and this seems to work just fine :-)

The reactive forms API doesn't provide signals yet, but there is a feature request with many upvotes: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53485. So we can expect that it will be supported in a future version of Angular. In the meantime, you can use toSignal() on the valueChanges observable, like the following:
myForm = new FormGroup({
  firstName: new FormControl(''),
});
firstName = toSignal(this.myForm.controls.firstName.valueChanges);
greetingText = computed(() => `Hello ${this.firstName()}!`);

If your form has an initial value, you can use the initialValue option of toSignal():
myForm = new FormGroup({
  firstName: new FormControl('John Doe'),
});
firstName = toSignal(
  this.myForm.controls.firstName.valueChanges,
  { initialValue: this.myForm.controls.firstName.value },
);
greetingText = computed(() => `Hello ${this.firstName()}!`);


Note that toSignal() is currently in developer preview and might undergo changes before becoming stable


Let's suppose my form has an initial value and that value is already is on a subject or another signal, how can I use that value of subject or signal for to initialised my form?

@AlirezaAhmadi for this case you can use the initialValue option of toSignal(), see my updated answer. You could also try to pipe startsWith() on the valueChanges observable. It looks not so clean, but until we have a native solution, I think there is no better way.

If you want to use Signals in NgModel you need to switch from signal to model and simplest way to achieve this is by following the sample below.
Working sample:
firstName = model('first name');

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="firstName" (ngModelChange)="firstName.set($event)"/>
{{ firstName() }}


This was not the question. The question is how to use signals with reactive forms. Your code example still uses template-driven forms.
